# SharePoint 2010 chart web part displaying web analytics

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-analytics

Have anybody used SP2010 out of the box chart web part to display web analytics data? e.g most viewed page etc. Or know if this is possible or a way around this? I can't seem to find anything that suggest that you can, would like to not use any third party tools.

Answer (score 0):

Noop. I worked on a similar assignment where I extracted data from WebAnalyticsServiceApplication_ db.

1. I created SharePoint TimeJob which extracts data periodically and adds into a sharepoint List.
2. Later created Sharepoint application page with charts.js and Jquery to display charts based on the sharepoint list.

Note it is not advisable to directly access SharePoint Database. But my case was approved by my company.

Comment: That's more than what I have meetkichu. How did you create the TimeJob?